# Macbook charge with an iPad charger

Tags: macbook-pro, ipad

Can I charge my MacBook (the new one, with the USB-C) with an iPad charger? I forgot my MacBook charger and may not be able to get it in a week. Thanks!

Comment: Lightning connector ≠ USB-C. There's also these special things called "voltage" and "current" that make it unwise to use a charger on anything other than its intended device because it might harm the battery. Unless you (or someone here) knows that iPads' and MacBooks' chargers have the same electrical specs I wouldn't charge your Mac with your iPad charger.

Comment: @Arc676 I don't think there's any danger here other than someone hoping for a charge to happen and it not happening. Connecting USB 2.0 charge to a MacBook that was designed to take power from USB 3.1 won't matter. You're right that 3.1 allows charging voltages of 20V, 12V in addition to the older 5V standard.

Answer (score 3):

The iPad charger is 10 W and the MacBook charger is 29 W, so you would really be limping along from a power source that's not sufficient. I haven't tested, but my guess is the MacBook won't even try to charge from that small power source.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201700

The second hurdle you will face is that you'll need a [charging cable to go from the iPad charger's USB A port to the USB C port](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00URK1V1U). This basically will connect the [4 wires](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#PD) the iPad charger uses to the [24 pins](http://www.anandtech.com/show/8539/usb-power-delivery-v20-and-billboard-device-class-v10-specifications-finalized) that the MacBook expects.

[image]

[image]

I wouldn't count on this doing anything and instead look for an Apple Adapter or third party adapter that adheres to the [USB Power Delivery specification - Apple specifically lists that this is supported](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204360) by the MacBook.